# Unexpected value ToasterModule Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular

I have been at this for 2.5 hours now and been thru multiple posts. Tried several suggestions on https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15763, which frustrated me as the source of the above error seems different.

I am on angular 5 and on build, I get the error:

> ERROR in : Unexpected value 'ToasterModule in .../node_modules/angular5-toaster/dist/bundles/angular5-toaster.umd.js' imported by the module 'AppModule in ../src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

the library don't have its own copy of node_modules. Its own `tsconfig.js` file is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "types": [ "jasmine", "node" ],
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
  },
  "include": [
    "angular5-toaster.ts",
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "bundles"
    ]
}
```

angular5-toaster/package.json (partial):

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "7.0.12",
"module": "angular5-toaster.js",
  "name": "angular5-toaster",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": ">=4.0.0 <=5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": ">=4.0.0 <=5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": ">=4.0.0 <=5.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.11"
  },
```

My app.module.ts:

```
  import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';
import {ToasterModule, ToasterService} from 'angular5-toaster';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,ToasterModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot(),

        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [ToasterService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "RLRC",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --ec true",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "gitbuild": "ng build --prod --base /start-angular/RLRC/master/dist/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.1.1",
    "ngx-treeview": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "yarn": "^1.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.6.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.17",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.51",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I notice angular5-toaster (version 1.0.2) wasn't added to the list of dependence above but adding it didnt make any difference either.

What could be the problem? I would appreciate help as i might face same problem with other libraries.

Comment: you had selected wrong module for toaster  use this module as this has large no of download and more stable than angular-5 toaster https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-toastr

Comment: Emm. Thanks @SantoshSingh Lemme see solutions before i change anything libraries now. I was honestly hoping a solution than a solution cos i have no idea of ng2-toastr will cause me the same problem.

Comment: That did it @SantoshSingh. and they are the same anyway so it is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a particular problem with AoT builds and [angular5-toaster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-toaster).

I solved this by switching to [ng2-toastr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-toastr) which appears to be more stable and offer the same functionality.

Comment: @joshcomley...ended up doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have ToasterService in the 'providers' section of your app module. The ToasterModule provides the service.

However, I don't think that's your entire problem.

I put a simple working example of using the library on StackBlitz, at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-msm5nn

Comment: Thanks @GreyBeardedGeek.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please "accept" it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer is convenient in the case when the use of the library is superficial, it is not deeply embedded in the project.
In my case, transferring from `angular5-toaster` to `ng2-toastr` would take much time. So I found another solution which can help others.
angular5-toaster suggests importing it as follow:

```
import {ToasterModule } from 'angular5-toaster';
```

I used direct approach:

```
import { ToasterModule } from './../../node_modules/angular5-toaster/angular5-toaster';
```

Comment: Hey Barabas...thanks. I honestly didn't see that in any of the directions. Does it compile easily and smoothly? I actually liked angular5-toaster for two reasons and wouldnt mind going back to it seriously.

Comment: @NieSelam `Does it compile easily and smoothly?` - For me yes, I hope this process will be smooth too for you.